# Content-Security-Policy conflict PayPal express checkout paypalobjects script

Tags: paypal, content-security-policy

As part of the PayPal Express checkout Flow you are obliged to use a PayPal script which loads a number of elements from various URLs. This is conflicting with my Content-Security-Policy, which we are required to have in order to be PCI compliant. I have had to remove the CSP to get express checkout to work.
Has anyone else solved this issue?

I can't post our Content-Security-Policy because it contains more links than my reputation allows.

Comment: Which paypal urls are conflicting with your rules? It should be enough to add www.paypal.com and www.paypalobjects.com

Comment: I could see in the console lots of resources being loaded from different domains each time by paypalobject.js. We had the same problem with Zopin (now Zendesk) and they gave us code that would fit the patterns of the urls that use. I have now got it working by adding the PayPal element in the connect-src. This is what I have added for PayPal:
script-src  https://www.paypalobjects.com; 
connect-src https://www.paypal.com; 
frame-src https://www.paypal.com;

Comment: We are still having problems with customers seeing the endless spinning wheel. Today a customer clicked the pay now button 26 times before it would work - then her transaction was completed.